# Getting Rails error "syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-migration

I am trying to migrate *subject_id* and *course_id* to the *users* table by typing:

```
rails generate migration add_course_id_and_subject_id_to_users course_id:integer, subject_id:integer
```

However, it results in the error:

> _add_course_id_and_subject_id_to_users.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is shell syntax, not Ruby syntax, so you need to drop the comma between you attribute defs:

```
rails generate migration add_course_id_and_subject_id_to_users course_id:integer subject_id:integer
```

With the comma, you're trying to add two fields, "course_id:integer," (comma!) and "subject_id:integer" with the types "integer," (comma!) and "integer", respectively.

Somewhere along the road, the generated Ruby code will have that syntax error and raise the exception.